# CentOS 7: ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)

Tags: linux, centos, openldap

Installed OpenLDAP with this command

```
# yum -y install openldap openldap-clients openldap-servers
```

Copied reference data structures:

```
# cp /usr/share/openldap-servers/DB_CONFIG.example /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG
```

Generated a password hash for 'test' by:

```
# slappasswd
```

In file `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif` added:

```
# olcRootPW: {SSHA}5lPFVw19zeh7LT53hQH69znzj8TuBrLv
# olcSuffix: dc=mydomain,dc=com
# olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
```

In file `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif` added:

```
# olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external ,cn=auth" read by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com" read by * none
```

In file `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif` added:

```
# olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
```

After all that steps I started service by `sudo service slapd start` command.

Now I want to add some basic schema:

```
# ldapadd -f /etc/openldap/schema/core.ldif  -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -w test
```

And at this step I get an error:

```
# adding new entry "cn=core,cn=schema,cn=config"
# ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

Why I actually get this error if I use olcRootDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also required to change in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif` file next lines:

```
 # olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com" manage by * none
```

There is also added `manage by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com"`.